# How do you stop listening to a socket.io channel?

Tags: socket.io

In socket.io, you can bind to a socket event/channel like this:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
   socket.on('news', function (data) {
   console.log(data);
   socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
 });
</script>
```

But how do you stop listening to the "news" event?

Comment: have a look at this answere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418697/how-to-unsubscribe-from-a-socket-io-subscription

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try, `socket.removeAllListeners("news");`

Comment: Thanks, I got that one from the post Gaurav posted but he never put it as an answer.

Answer (score 10):

The `off` function can also be used.

- `socket.off('news'); // stops listening to the "news" event`
- `socket.off('news', myFunction); // useful if you have multiple listeners for the same event`
- `socket.off(); // stops listening to all events`

---

#### Sources

According to the [Socket.io Client Documentation](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-on-eventName-callback) "the socket actually inherits every method of the Emitter class, like `hasListeners`, `once` or `off` (to remove an event listener)."

[Emitter documentation](https://github.com/component/emitter#emitteroffevent-fn):

> - Pass `event` and `fn` to remove a listener.
> - Pass `event` to remove all listeners on that event.
> - Pass nothing to remove all listeners on all events.

Comment: The same is for Android. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove only a specific event you can try `socket.removeListener('you_event');`