# Socket io returns two arrays after singing out and signing back in

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want socket io to send an array to the client side. This is successful when the user first signs in, however when the user signs out and then sign back in, socket io sends out two of the same array. I can't seem to figure out why it does this.
here is my code server side:

```
var object = [];
  query.find({
    success: function(results){
      for(var i=0; i< results.length; i++){
        var file = results[i].toJSON();
        for(var k in file){
          if (k ==="javaFile"){
            for(var t in file[k]){
               if (t === "name"){
                  temp = file[k][t];
                  var getname = temp.split("-").pop();
                  object[i] = getname;

               }                  
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit("FileName", object);
     console.log(object);
  });
```

this is my client side:

```
socket.on('FileName', function(data){
var name = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(data);
 clients[socket.id] = socket;
```

Comment: you are not unsubscribing to the socket when you log out. so your socket.on('FileName') is registered twice.

Answer (score 0):

When you are logging out make sure you unsubscribe from the listeners.

Something like this should work :

```
socket.removeAllListeners("FileName");
```

Alternatively you can unsub like so :

```
socket.removeListener("FileName");
```

Ref : [Google Groups Discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/socket_io/6riFqbVRy0Y)

This means the next time you come along and login there is only 1 subscription to emit to.

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418697/how-to-unsubscribe-from-a-socket-io-subscription)

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. I get `TypeError: listener must be a function`. In my routes under signout I wrote `io.on('disconnect', function(socket){socket.removeAllListener('FileName')});`

Comment: @wisemen its `socket.removeAllListeners` you are missing an S at the end

Comment: I tried that too, it doesn't work. socket.removeAllListeners, I don't get any error message, however it doesn't remove the listener.