# Socket Io client creates multiple listener on Vue Componet

Tags: socket.io, vue.js, vuejs2

I am Using Vue.js as the front-end framework.

I am adding the socket.io listener on a component using created life-cycle hook.

```
created () {
    // socket listener
    this.$socket.on('event', (response) => { .... })
}
```

Now if the component is unmounted and later remounted then two listener are created.

I tried using "once" in place of "on" but same problem.

How Can I make sure that only one Listener is active?

Note: The socket component is added to Vue as Instance Property.

Comment: Why not use [Vue-socketIO](https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what `$socket` is, but the way you handle this is to remove the listener when the component is destroyed.

```
methods:{
  handleEvent(response) { ... }
},
created(){
  this.$socket.on('event', this.handleEvent)
},
beforeDestroy(){
  // using "removeListener" here, but this should be whatever $socket provides
  // for removing listeners
  this.$socket.removeListener('event', this.handleEvent)
}
```

I based the method `removeListener` off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418697/how-to-unsubscribe-from-a-socket-io-subscription) but it may be some other method for removing listeners depending on your library.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The $socket holds the IO Object created during connection. I will try your solution and mark it as correct if it works.