# Socket.io socket.off() not working as expected

Tags: socket.io

I was trying to remove all event listeners from a socket, to a specific event, and found this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34716449/2691879) on StackOveflow.

I followed the answer, and tried the following: `socket.off('listenerName')` to remove all listeners from the `listenerName` event, but this code gives me an error:

```
(node:27706) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type Function. Received type undefined
```

I am using the latest version (*2.3.0*) of `socket.io`. So it looks like, that the `socket.off()` method needs at least 2 parameters to work, and I have to explicitly tell it which function I want to remove. I tried searching `socket.io`'s documentation to find the definition of this function, but all I found is that the `socket` inherits every method from the `Emiter`, including the `off()` method as well.

Does anyone know if there is a function in `socket.io`, with which I can remove all listeners from a specific event, without explicitly providing it a reference to the originally added function?

Comment: I don't know how you got from an answer citing `socket.off('event_name')` amd `socket.off('event_name', listener)` to your code of `socket.off('listenerName')`. Try reading more carefully.

Comment: I think what you are saying, is just a naming problem, in the following line, what would you call `event_name`? `socket.on('disconnect', function() {});` ? because I would call `listenerName` the disconnect string. And by doing `socket.off('disconnect')` with socket.io 2.3.0, I get the above error. So if I am mistaken, and the `event_name` is not the same which I call `listenerName`, then pardon me, and I will correct my answer. but if not, maybe you should read more carefully, before downvoting and commenting.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9696077/2691879).

I've managed to remove all the event listeners from the specific event with:

```
socket.removeAllListeners("news");
```