# How to unsubscribe socket io in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, socket.io

This how I connect client to server with socket io.

```
export class OverviewService {

  socket:any;
  readonly uri:string='http://localhost:4000';

  

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.socket = io(this.uri);
   }
```

and this when I call

```
getOnPeak(){
    this.socket.emit('on_peak/today');

    return new Observable((subscriber)=>{
      this.socket.on('on_peak/today',(data:any)=>{
        subscriber.next(data.onPeak.toFixed(2))
        console.log('onPeak:'+data.onPeak.toFixed(2));
      })
    })
    
  }
```

overview.ts

```
this.getOnPeekSub=this.overviewService.getOnPeak().subscribe(onPeak => {
      this.onPeak = onPeak;
    })
```

on **ngOnDestroy** i tried to use removeAllListeners(),removeListeners() and off() but it doesn't work .

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418697/how-to-unsubscribe-from-a-socket-io-subscription

Answer (score 0):

```
getOnPeak(){
    this.socket.emit('on_peak/today');

    return new Observable((subscriber)=>{
      this.socket.on('on_peak/today',(data:any)=>{
        subscriber.next(data.onPeak.toFixed(2))
        console.log('onPeak:'+data.onPeak.toFixed(2));
      })

      return function unsubscribe() {
        this.socket.disconnect()
      };
    })
    
  }
```

When you unsubscribe from the Observalbe, the socket will be closed.
Read more here https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable (Disposing Observable Executions)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't solve the issue .This is my backend code **socket.on('on_peak/today', (message) => { setInterval(async () => { console.log('on_peak/today') socket.emit('on_peak/today', await onPeakToday()); }, 3000); });**

That why client always emit when I re-reder the screen. that make heap out of memory.

How to fix it?